# Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Tags: c#, remoting

I done an application in .NET Remoting. I register a port (8085) in my server application. I have 2000 clients they all send an update every 2min to my server through the same port (8085). I often get an error:

> Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

2000 Clients -----> From 2000 Different Machines to the port 8085 in the server

Comment: please edit and clean up the code - also, may be a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905230/tcp-socket-error-only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-protocol-network-address

Answer (score 1):

[See this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/666798d3-fc9a-4906-b1b8-0b26d8edf1a4) for details on the problem. I suggest you stop requiring a particular port number on the client side, that's not generally needed.

Comment: Actually my application listens on 8085 port in a machine,if clients
want to send a message means its only through the port 8085,how to avoid this